# how to check char array with nested if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement

As you might be able to tell im trying to introduce a counter for how many consonants there are in a certain string, but the output is always 50, unless spaces are involved.

```
int main(){
char input[50];
int total = 0;
cout << "Enter a string of no more than 50 characters\n";
cin.getline(input,50);

for(int n = 0; n<50;n++){
    if(input[n]!='a',input[n]!='A',input[n]!='e',input[n]!='E',input[n]!='i',input[n]!='I',input[n]!='o',input[n]!='O',input[n]!='u',input[n]!='U',input[n]!=' ')
    total++;}

cout << total << endl;}
```

Comment: The comma operator doesn't do what you think it does, use `&&` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has clearly explained, you need to use && operator to ensure all conditions are checked.

```
    if(input[n]!='a' && input[n]!='A' && input[n]!='e' && input[n]!='E' && input[n]!='i' && input[n]!='I' && input[n]!='o' && input[n]!='O' && input[n]!='u' && input[n]!='U' && input[n]!=' '){
    total++;
}
```

One recommendation to avoid multiple checks:
Extract the character to a variable converted to lower or upper case.

```
char c = input[n] | 32;
```

Regarding the ',' used; this program might provide more insight along with the [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) shared :

```
void main(){
    int a=-1;
    if(++a,a, a++){ // Works like "||"
       printf("Yes %d",a); 
    }else {
       printf("NO %d", a);
    } 
}
```

> Output: NO 1

Answer (score 3):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), comma operator is defined as follows

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

In your case, you should use logical AND (&&) instead of comma operation.
More efficiently, you may rewrite your code like this

```
char c = tolower(input[n]);
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && c != 'a' && c != 'e' && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c !='u')
    total++;
```

It will include all the cases.